# WebSocket connection issues using c#

Tags: c#, sockets

The response from the server is not a valid HTTP response. This problem occurs when the .NET Framework detects that the server response does not comply with HTTP 1.1 RFC. This problem may occur when the response contains incorrect headers or incorrect header delimiters.RFC 2616 defines HTTP 1.1 and the valid format for the response from the server. For more information, see RFC 2616 - Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1 at Internet Engineering Task Force (IETF) website.

Get a network trace of the transaction and examine the headers in the response.

If your application requires the server response without parsing (this could be a security issue), set useUnsafeHeaderParsing to true in the configuration file. See  Element

Comment: You’ll need to show some code. Most likely you’re sending the wrong length of data, or the receiving end is doing receiving wrong.

Comment: TCP is a *stream of bytes*, not *messages*. If you want messages, it's up to *you* to implement messaging atop TCP, or to shift to a higher level protocol that does this for you. Likely the issue here is that you're ignoring the return value from `Read` (or other equivalents on the receive side) which tells you *how many bytes have just been placed in your buffer*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you just forgentting to clear the buffer before you receive new message.
2 quick options for you:

-add '\0' in the end of each of your messages on your server side. This will prevent gliches like that from happening.

-use Array.Clear(buffer,0,buffer.length) to clear buffer before receiving on your client side.